# Why does python2 save text with encoding escape characters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

The script reads a file with my copy-pasted text in it. It does some manipulations on the text data and returns the result. 
However when python reads the file it saves it in a variable with single quotes and some other chars encoded like: `\xe2\x80\x99`, `\xe2\x80\x9`, `\xe2\x80\x99` and so on. 
This happens only when I copy-paste the text from a webpage. If I type in the same text into a file and read that file afterwards, single quotes and other chars are not escaped with special characters.

The file's name is 'text.txt'. I open it with an editor that saves everything in utf-8 by default. I open up a news web page (for example: http://www.euronews.com/2013/05/31/why-it-s-not-so-great-in-britain/) and copy the text into the 'text.txt' file. Afterwards: `file=open('text.txt', 'r').read()` and hit `file` in python2 console.

```
In [62]: file=open('text.txt', 'r').read()

In [63]: file
Out[63]: 'Britain\xe2\x80\x99s generous system... David Cameron:\xe2\x80\x9c What we can do is make sure...they\xe2\x80\x99re drawn by the attractiveness...\xe2\x80\x9d'
```

**1) Could you explain such behaviour?**

**2) How can I make python read in the copied text without escape characters?**

Comment: Please show us how are you reading the file and how do you display the read data.

Comment: You could try a `line.decode('utf-8', 'replace')` and see if it fixes it. Also, if you want to learn a bit more about encoding I would highly suggest reading this: http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: with `file.decode('utf-8','replace')` I'm getting utf-8 escapes: `Britain\u2019s`, `they\u2019re` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [1]: text = 'perchè'

In [2]: text
Out[2]: 'perch\xc3\xa8'

In [3]: print text
perchè
```

When you evaluate something ipython calls its `repr` method. The `repr` method of strings shows the escapes instead of the actual characters. This is what you actually want, since it avoids problems with stdout encoding and also allows you to see what characters are actually in the string(think of unicode multi-ways of obtaining the same character).

To see the real characters you should write the string to stdout(assuming stdout can handle the encoding of the string etc.)

Comment: I was getting the same output in IDLE2 on both windows and linux machines. But the tip about ipython is very useful, thank you.

Comment: @minerals What I wrote is valid for pretty much *any* interactive interpreter. Ipython's qt console and notebook have a different behaviour regarding objects(e.g. they allow to show pictures/latex formulae etc.), but the strings are always shown as I described.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that for some reason *euronews.net* webpage texts are displayed this way. When I copy any text with quotes from any other site, I have only simple `don\'t` escapes in it.